Azure Logic Apps - API Connections between Logic App and Resource got wildly out of sync and throttled the app. How?
I've got a Standard Logic App that handles a series of file transfers between legacy systems. Nothing crazy, under 50 a day in total at different times.
I've been updating one of the connections from SFTP to a File System connector (as it's going through a data gateway onto an on-prem integration server) - and managed to mess up our test Logic App in a really weird way. I've solved it (and will say how for anyone else who experiences the same) but I wanted to know how this could have happened and how to avoid it again in the future. Apologies, it's a long post-mortem.
Here's the series of events as I remember it:

Create a new file system connection via the Designer using the (not in-app) File System connector (Change Connection -> Add New)
I (absentmindedly) copy the display name from another connection for the naming convention but do not update it. There are now two connections with the same display name (but, as far I know, this doesn't matter - that's not their ID behind the scenes).
The connection does not list the files on the server. I raise another connection, thinking I've mistyped the credentials. I definitely update the display name this time.
It doesn't work. I try a few more configurations. Eventually, I move a .py file out of the folder that I'm trying to access on the server (one that syncs with a different location), set up a new connection, and it works this time (weird).
I go to remove the previous connections in the main Connections blade (next to workflows and parameters). This only shows me the first one I made, with the duplicate display name (say, file-system-5)
Clicking on said file-system-5 actually displays the API connection page for file-system-4 (the original connection I copied the display from).
Deleting file-system-5 does not remove it - but instead becomes a dead link (goes to 'resource cannot be found'). It's status is now 'Access Policies are missing'.
Going back into the workflow, we can see all the connections if you go by the File System connector. But not if you go into the main Connections page.

Meanwhile, our Logic App is now being throttled. Every time I go into the workflow Designer, we get 'invalid connection' errors on all File System connectors. Trying to select the right connection again brings up the 'New Connection' page, as if we hadn't already got around 10 available and we are starting from a blank page. This happens intermittently, with good days and bad days. It disrupts dev time, as you're unable to save any open designer with this error.
If you inspect the console, you can see quite a lot of STATUS: 429 errors from the resource, which indicates throttling - but no indication of this in the actual GUI.
We also intermittently now get storage issues - the Logic App in test goes down with the error 'Network path not found', and references being unable to find the secrets file in Sentinel on the C: drive. I confirm they are there with Kudu. This also happens on both our test resource and our production resource.
We also get timing issues with our blob storage - copying a file from a 'hot' container into an 'archive' container, and then deleting the hot file now introduces MissingLeaseID errors, suggesting that the lease isn't being released properly. Putting in a 1 min delay between the two sometimes works.
Clearly, I totally messed this up.
Solved by:

The File System is one of the more constrained API connections you can have when it comes to limits - although this should be per connection.
I suspect that Azure was polling all of my file system connections each time I opened the designer, which was hitting some sort of limit. I don't know why this stopped us from being able to access our connections at all.
This was problematic, because I couldn't remove the unused connections via the workflow designer, but they weren't being listed in the main Connections page either. So I was stuck polling these connections for no reason and using up my quota.
I later discovered that you can also access these connections via the resource group, not just the Logic App. I deleted all the unused connections from there, and copied the JSON from the working connection I had.
I went back to the Connections page in the Logic App, went to the JSON and manually re-entered the working connection and had to remove the entries for the unused connections here as well. Saved.
Went back through all the workflows, went into code view, and manually updated their file system connection references to the correct one.
Went into the designer, and then had to manually reset all the connections here too, to the correct one (which I guess was also being cached).

The issue now seems to be resolved (thanks for reading all that).
What I don't understand is how the workflows, the main Connections JSON, and the resource API connections got so wildly out of sync. Are they not all pulling from the same definition behind the screen?
Thanks again for reading - appreciate any insight on how to better manage this in the future.

Is your issue resolved? If yes, then add it as an answer

No - I haven't had any guidance on why the error occurred in the first place yet.
